# PhoneGap create pages dynamically in mobile app

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-build

I have a PhoneGap mobile application that has a couple of predefined "html pages" (I used the double quotes, because they're not actual html files).
I used the onsen-ui framework for it, so I can put all the "html" pages in ONE index.html file.

I create the pages like this:

```
<ons-template id="login.html">  
    <ons-page ng-controller="LoginController" id="login">
        <ons-toolbar>
            <div class="center">Log In</div>
        </ons-toolbar>
        <div class="login-form">
            <input type="text" class="text-input--underbar" placeholder="Username" ng-model="email">
            <input type="password" class="text-input--underbar" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password">
            <br><br>
            <ons-button modifier="large" class="login-button" ng-click="checkLogin(email,password)" > Log In</ons-button>
        </div>
    </ons-page>
</ons-template>
```

As you can see, I have a **Controller** connected to this page, called LoginController which is defined in the main.js javascript file, which is the engine of the whole application. In order to do / show anything in the view, it has to have a controller and functions defined.

Is it possible, to dynamically add these **ons-template>ons-page>** elements to the index.html file, from php, so we can "update" the app, without actually changing anything on the application? Also, this would *probably* only work if the main.js file is also updated with a new controller, or should it be a generic one?

The app is used for showing info from a database, and we would like to add new "views" dynamically, which would show different data from the database.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at Microsoft's [Code Push](https://microsoft.github.io/code-push/) which is a plugin and server component designed to do update app content without an App Store update.